# Creating multiple A-records from windows server via dynamic-dns

Tags: windows, networking, dns, hostname, cname

I have a windows server (2012 R2) joined to domain. Server has 2 NICs, each with different IP address.

It is easy to create multiple static A-records on Domain Controller's DNS to give a name for each IP on the server, however, I need to achieve the same from the server-end.

Is it possible to have multiple DNS-A records created from within a single windows server via dynamic-DNS updates?

Server seems to associate all its IPs with his hostname only("register this connections addresses with DNS").

[Netdom](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/josebda/2010/06/04/multiple-names-for-one-computer-consolidate-your-smb-file-servers-without-breaking-unc-paths/) seems to create CNAMEs, not A-records:

```
NETDOM COMPUTERNAME cfile /ADD file1.contoso.local
NETDOM COMPUTERNAME cfile /ADD file2.contoso.local
NETDOM COMPUTERNAME cfile /ADD file2.contoso.local
IPCONFIG /registerdns
```